# Is it possible to set points without coordinates onto a map?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, qgis-2.10, indoor

I have the following Situation:
csv-file with 1000 lines of measurements. These measurements were done indoor in a building without GPS. The measurement-system allows to set "markers" at any time.
Afterwards i would like to "georeference" the measurement with these markers in QGIS 2.10.1.
The csv looks like this (fake data, just to get an idea what i mean):

```
id time event value
0 12:00:00 marker 0
1 12:00:01 ? 2
2 12:00:02 ? 5
3 12:00:03 ? 2
4 12:00:04 marker 1
5 12:00:05 ? 9
6 12:00:06 ? 2
7 12:00:07 marker 7
...
```

Is it now possible with QGIS 2.10.1 to define the Position of the markers (red dots) through a mouseclick whereever I want on a room plan? Also would it be nice when the program distributes the measurements equally in between two markers as a line.
[image]